# What would be the best way to hide an element unless a different element has focus in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Basically, I have a search bar and predictions that show up below it. I want the predictions to be hidden unless the search bar has focus.
There are lots of ways to implement this so I was wondering what do you think would be the best way to go about this and why?

Comment: You can do that with just css 

elementFocus:focus #yourPredictions{display:block}

Comment: @cport1 - that will only work if `#yourPredictions` is a child of `elementFocus`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ng-hide and ng-focus:-

```
<input type="text" ng-focus="showme=true">
<div ng-hide="showme">

in controller 
$scope.showme=false;
```

plunker:-
http://plnkr.co/edit/FHHeYRn8VGLx2tcMTF0M?p=preview

Comment: This is by far best option, but don't forget to add `ng-blur="showme=false"` to hide element

Comment: sorry for that @maurycy